# Any template for developing Jolie’s extensions?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, intellij-plugin, netbeans-plugins, jolie

I am developing a Jolie (jolie-lang.org) extension, a service-oriented programming language, for handling CoAP message communication. 
I was wondering if there exists any Java code template for doing that properly.
 - From the official documentation on GitBook I can’t see anything related. 
 - There exists a official GitHub repo of Jolie, maintained by community developers, but extensions already there have different implementations.

Do you know of any template or IDE-related plugin to develop extensions in Jolie?

Comment: Please do not put any links to external websites in your question. If, after some time, the link does not exist anymore, the question will become of no use for other readers. Please rephrase your question in a way that the link is not anymore necessary.

Comment: Not sure to understand why links are a problem. If you are suggesting that broken-links should be automatically fixed (by removing them) somehow, you should point that to stack overflow. Links are helpful at an early stage of the developing of a proper answer, to understand the context of the question. Links will not be broken the day after the question is made, but after some time, in the meanwhile, in my opinion, they are helpful.

Comment: It is policy here not to use external links, because the value of stackoverflow for the largest part is from archived questions and answers which include all necessary information. Stackoverflow cannot control external links. That is the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know there is no template for developing a plugin in Eclipse or any of the mentioned.
The only fully functional plugin is Atom you can use [Atom Jolie](https://atom.io/packages/atom-jolie) and work from there.
A good starting point is [How to built your atom plugin](https://blog.github.com/2016-08-19-building-your-first-atom-plugin/), yet atom plugin development is not small things.
Hope it helps